# ServerManager.OpenRemote error 80040154 CLSID {2b72133b-3f5b-4602-8952-803546ce3344} in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: iis-7.5, windows, iis, asp.net-mvc

I have a console app, which is using Microsoft.Web.Administration to remotely manage IIS on remote server (I used this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458410/credentials-for-servermanager-openremote - modified ahadmin properties, opened TCP port 135. I also used impersonation). Everything works fine - I can remotely create Sites and App Pools and so on.

But when I'm trying to do the same thing in ASP.NET MVC 4 app, I get this error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class
>   factory for remote component with CLSID
>   {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine "remoteServerIP"
>   failed due to the following error: 80040154 "remoteServerIP".

I know many people get this error, and I saw a lot of posts about it, but nothing worked for me. I tried switching my MVC app to platform target X86 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-t?rq=1), on remote machine I enabled full permissions for both HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{2b72133b-3f5b-4602-8952-803546ce3344} and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{2b72133b-3f5b-4602-8952-803546ce3344} for the account that I'm using to impersonate.
The problem seems to be in some difference between MVC and console apps, but I can't figure out what it is.

I'm on Windows 7 x64, remote server - windows server 2008 R2 x64. There's IIS 7.5 on both machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The issue was the fact that my MVC app was using a wrong version of Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll.

When I was debugging console app, I was able to get a list of sites from local IIS using this code

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
```

and a list of sites from remote IIS using this code

```
ServerManager serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("remoteServerIpAddress");
```

and everything was OK. Then I put exactly the same code in an MVC app, and when I tried to get a list of sites from remote IIS I got the exception from the question. When trying to get a list of sites from local IIS, I got websites from IIS Express. Server Manager seemed to connect to IIS Express instead of full IIS, but I didn't pay much attention to this at first. Unfortunately.

Accidentally I found this post Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager looking in wrong directory for IISExpress applicationHost.config, from where I found out that

> If the application, in which you are using
>   Microsoft.Web.Administration ..., is running on IISExpress, it will
>   always fallback to Microsoft.Web.Administration version 7.9.0.0 due to
>   an assembly redirect in the aspnet.config in the IIS express.

I was using IIS Express to debug, and it redirected me to wrong version of Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll - 7.9.0.0, and I needed 7.0.0.0, which is used by full IIS. So I hosted my MVC app on full local IIS, debugged it there and it worked! I successfully retrieved a list of sites from remote IIS. Hope it helps someone.